# Simple question about eigenvalue / matrix multiplication.

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a very elementary question, so please bear with me.

I am trying to understand SVD. A [textbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=60CAolt0cpgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Advanced+Lectures+on+Machine+Learning:+ML+Summer+Schools+2003,+Canberra+...&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3Q1hVNGpOfbdsASY9ILABw&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Advanced%20Lectures%20on%20Machine%20Learning%3A%20ML%20Summer%20Schools%202003%2C%20Canberra%20...&f=false/) says:

> Let $x_{i} \in R^{m}$  be an eigenvector of $AA^{T}$ with positive eigenvalue $\sigma_{i}^{2}$ and let $y_{i} = (1/ \sigma_{i} )(A^{T}x_{i}), y \in R^{n}.$ Then, $A^{T}Ay_{i} = (1/\sigma_{i})A^{T}AA^{T}x_{i} = \sigma_{i}A^{T}x_{i} = \sigma^{2}_{i}y_{i}$ .

Since $A^{T}A = I$, I thought $(\frac{1} \sigma_{i})A^{T}AA^{T}x_{i}$ =
$(\frac{1} \sigma_{i})A^{T}x_{i}$ . 
Then why does $\sigma_{i}A^{T}x_{i}$ =
$(\frac{1} \sigma_{i})A^{T}x_{i}$ ? Where am I going wrong?

The rest of that line makes sense to me.

Comment: $A^TA=I$ if and only if $A$ is real orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $A^TA = I$ isn't true. I'm sure you can come with some examples. Were you perhaps getting that confused with the result being a symmetric matrix?

By definition of $x_i$ being an eigenvector of $AA^T$, then $AA^Tx_i=\sigma_i^2x_i$ so $A^T(AA^Tx_i)=A^T\sigma_i^2x_i$. Introducing the $y_i$ leads to the rest.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. That was silly of me. Thanks!